# Can glucose burn in chlorine?

Tags: combustion, carbohydrates

Chlorine is an oxidizing agent, so could it replace oxygen? If so, what would be the products, and how much energy would such reactions release? Do any other carbohydrates burn in chlorine? I cannot find any information on this.

Clarification: How does glucose interact with chlorine chemically?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64541/is-oxygen-necessary-for-burning https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19883/fire-resistance-of-pvc

Comment: It shouldn't work for same reason as why PVC is difficult to put on fire, IMO.

Comment: "Burn" is typically used only to described reactions with oxygen.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't quite see the analogy. ;-) The reaction yields HCl, and will definitely work. Ok, sugar even doesn't burn very well in oxygen.

Comment: @MaxW Not necessarily, you can make flame with various other oxidants, fluorine would work even in cases when oxygen isn't strong enough.

Comment: @Mithoron I wanted to say in air. In pure oxygen, sugar burns as well as practically everything else except rocks.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of glucose being burned in chlorine, but I do know that glucose reacts with chlorine in aqueous-buffer medium. See reference 1.
The full paper is behind a paywall.

It says that oxidation of glucose by bromine water was studied previously and the reaction of glucose and aqueous chlorine also happens in a similar fashion although the reaction is slow and products yield is less. Nonetheless, **major product of the reaction is D-gluconic acid in both acidic and alkaline medium** but unbuffered chlorine may further react with D-gluconic acid to various products like 5-keto-D-gluconic acid and D-glucaric acid.

**Reference**

1. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1955**, *77* (7), 1875–1880. [DOI: 10.1021/ja01612a050](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01612a050).